# How to convert vector image files to SVG with inkscape, when I don't know the extension

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, file-extension, inkscape

*TL;DR: Is there a way to tell Inkscape on the command line, what the file extension is of the parameter --file=?*

I have a case where I have to convert vector image files to SVG, using Inkscape command line tool. Current code is targeted at PDFs, so the following works fine:

```
inkscape --without-gui --file=source_file.pdf --export-plain-svg=result_file.svg
```

My problem is that I have to apply the same to new files, that are stored without extension, so my command would look like this:

```
inkscape --without-gui --file=some_stored_file --export-plain-svg=result_file.svg
```

When I run this command I get an error: "Specified document some_stored_file cannot be opened (does not exist or not a valid SVG file)"

I think this happens because the file doesn't have an extension and Inkscape can't guess the format.

What I can do is: get the format somewhere else, copy the stored file to a temp file with extension (some_temp_file.pdf) and then convert that to SVG, then remove the new temp file.

While this works fine, I would skip the otherwise unnecessary file copying just to have an extension.

**Is there a way to tell Inkscape what the file extension is, other than having a file extension explicitely?**

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't found an answer to my question so what I did is symlinking the file (instead of copying), adding the extension on the symlink. Still better than copying the file and works fine.